AstroJs - astro images not displaying when site proxied through CDN after upgrade to Astro V5
Referenced images contained within the src folder display when navigating to the website from the server itself which ignores the CDN. When navigating normally from a browser off the server (passing through CDN), these images do not display. They will display after I navigate to the page with the image on the server itself. This seems to have occurred with upgrade of Astro from V4 to V5 (latest).
The following is a simple code example of what I am trying to do. I can probably change image references to refer to images in the public folder, but will lose any astro image optimization.
---
import { Image } from "astro:assets";
import shape from "@/images/gd-site-shape-img-small.png";
---
<Image
        src={shape}
        alt="shape"
        class="w-[110px] absolute top-[-20px] right-[32%] hidden md:block"
      />

